# Why does the Windows Task Manager show two threads when running int main() {} from VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, process, cmd

When launching the following program from Visual Studio:

```
int main()
{
    for (;;)
        ; // ignore undefined behavior or imagine your favorite calculation here
}
```

Windows Task Manager shows two threads for that process.

What's the second thread? The emulated Windows command shell? If so, what is the launch sequence?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1faTFQ-5LQ

Comment: BTW your program has undefined behaviour; it would be better to examine a program with well-defined behaviour.

Comment: To expand on PreferenceBean's comment, a program that enters and infinite loop with no observable side effect is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: I really do not think that is the issue.  Even running a hello world program from MSVS shows two threads in the task manager.

Comment: I didn't say I think it is - but let's examine well-defined programs as a matter of course.

Comment: Well, when running a console application in MSVC under a debugger, I can see 4 threads: 1 main thread + 3 Worker threads from `ntdll.dll`. What's the purpose of them? Haven't got a clue.

Comment: Crystal ball say that you are using Window 10.  The loader was optimized to load dependent DLLs concurrently using threadpool threads.  @Algirdas certainly does.  If not then an injected DLL can easily start a thread itself, anti-malware etcetera.

Comment: @HansPassant I am running windows & and I get the same thing.

Comment: Try running the binary directly without the debugger, I believe the debugger spawns a thread in order to break in etc. But even without the debugger, it's normal to see additional threads in the process, which are spawned indirectly due to OS/API calls.